# Suggesting a matching string using Levenstein distance algorithm is too slow

Tags: c++, performance

I have a that function returns an sf::EventType based on a string provided by a user. If there is no match, the functions returns sf::nullopt. But I would like to print a suggested, valid, sf::EventType, that is the closest to what the user provided, to help with misspellings etc.

There are 'only' 13 valid sf::EventType's that have to be checked for the closest match, and i'm assuming that a user wont enter some ridiculusly long string.

On my laptops m3-7Y30 intel processor I have tested the functions speed on both debug and release mode:

~45 seconds on debug
~3 seconds on release

Huge difference, but still I feel like 3 seconds is a bit much given that the user might provide anywhere from 5 to 100 event types.

Given these results I doubt that this approach to suggest a valid sf::EventType could be optimized enough to make it viable, but if it can, I would like to know how. If not, I would like a suggestion for an alternative, that would still print a suggestion, no matter how far off the provided string is.

The relevant code looks like this:

**convertToSfEvent**

```
std::optional<sf::Event::EventType> EventFileReader::convertToSfEvent(std::string_view event)
    {
        if      (event == "Closed")              return sf::Event::EventType::Closed;
        else if (event == "Resized")             return sf::Event::EventType::Resized;
        else if (event == "LostFocus")           return sf::Event::EventType::LostFocus;
        else if (event == "GainedFocus")         return sf::Event::EventType::GainedFocus;
        else if (event == "TextEntered")         return sf::Event::EventType::TextEntered;
        else if (event == "KeyPressed")          return sf::Event::EventType::KeyPressed;
        else if (event == "KeyReleased")         return sf::Event::EventType::KeyReleased;
        else if (event == "MouseWheelScrolled")  return sf::Event::EventType::MouseWheelScrolled;
        else if (event == "MouseButtonPressed")  return sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonPressed;
        else if (event == "MouseButtonReleased") return sf::Event::EventType::MouseButtonReleased;
        else if (event == "MouseMoved")          return sf::Event::EventType::MouseMoved;
        else if (event == "MouseEntered")        return sf::Event::EventType::MouseEntered;
        else if (event == "MouseLeft")           return sf::Event::EventType::MouseLeft;
        else
        {
            // Heres is where I search for a match, and the recursion madness starts
            auto smallest_required_change{ INT_MAX };
            auto closest_string{ std::string() };
            for (auto event_type : this->event_types)
            {
                auto result{ levensteinDistance(event, event_type, event.length(), event_type.length()) };

                if (result < smallest_required_change)
                {
                    smallest_required_change = result;
                    closest_string = event_type;
                }
            }

            std::cerr << "Could not recognize event_type token: '" << event << "' did you mean: '" << closest_string << "'?" << "\n";

            return std::nullopt;
        }
    }
```

**levensteinDistance**

```
std::size_t EventFileReader::levensteinDistance(std::string_view first, std::string_view second, std::size_t first_pos, std::size_t second_pos)
    {
        static auto one{ std::size_t(1) };

        if (!first_pos)
            return first_pos;

        if (!second_pos)
            return second_pos;

        if (first[first_pos - one] == second[second_pos - one])
            return levensteinDistance(first, second, first_pos - one, second_pos - one);

        return 1 + std::min({ levensteinDistance(first, second, first_pos,       second_pos - one),
                              levensteinDistance(first, second, first_pos - one, second_pos),
                              levensteinDistance(first, second, first_pos - one, second_pos - one)
                           });
    }
```

Comment: Are you testing a optimized release build or a unoptimized debug build?

Comment: Hey Jesper, I was indeed using debug build - mistake on my part - I have updated my question to include release build - which has a huge boost, but is still slower than I like.

Comment: I suspect the levensteinDistance algorithm you are using is not the most efficient one.  I use the algorithm at the following link and find it acceptably fast; you might give it a try instead:  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C.2B.2B

Comment: Your `else` branch in `EventFileReader::convertToSfEvent` looks suspicious. You do a bunch of work but *always* return `std::nullopt` regardless of how that work turns out - that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, the code might not be the cleanest - the function should return nullopt given that it could not find an approiate 'eventType', the "extra work" is the code that prints a suggested 'eventType', but even though it might find that, it should still return nullopt, as the closest match might not be what the user intended.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Indeed this seems to have been my problem. The algorithm I used was taken from "GeeksForGeeks" (link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/edit-distance-dp-5/) and is apperently complete garbage (Note the site does indeed mention that the approach used is naive, but I was too tunnelvisioned on the code to read that paragraph). The implementation you provided from your link makes the function execute pretty much instantly. If youd like you can add your comment as an answer, and I will accept it, as this was indeed the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `levenshtein` implementation is recursive and slow, you may want to change that to a faster one, for example (source: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
// Compute Levenshtein Distance
// Martin Ettl, 2012-10-05

size_t uiLevenshteinDistance(const std::string &s1, const std::string &s2)
{
  const size_t m(s1.size());
  const size_t n(s2.size());

  if( m==0 ) return n;
  if( n==0 ) return m;

  size_t *costs = new size_t[n + 1];

  for( size_t k=0; k<=n; k++ ) costs[k] = k;

  size_t i = 0;
  for ( std::string::const_iterator it1 = s1.begin(); it1 != s1.end(); ++it1, ++i )
  {
    costs[0] = i+1;
    size_t corner = i;

    size_t j = 0;
    for ( std::string::const_iterator it2 = s2.begin(); it2 != s2.end(); ++it2, ++j )
    {
      size_t upper = costs[j+1];
      if( *it1 == *it2 )
      {
          costs[j+1] = corner;
      }
      else
      {
        size_t t(upper<corner?upper:corner);
        costs[j+1] = (costs[j]<t?costs[j]:t)+1;
      }

      corner = upper;
    }
  }

  size_t result = costs[n];
  delete [] costs;

  return result;
}
```

Or you may check this page for the inspiration: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#C